# Finding One Origin by using Triangle Calculation and Least Square in 3D

Tags: triangles, least-squares

I have been working on an assignment to find the exact origin from 2 points. I have a plane equation that contains 8 points (P1 and P8) and 4 angels from a combination of 2 points.
P1 and P2 with angel 60 degrees also known as OP1 = OP2 (Isoclese Triangle), I can find two origin O1 and O2.

[image]

Same go to P3, P4 with angel 40 degrees, P5, P6 with angel 50 degrees, P7, P8 with angel 60 degrees, we will get 2 origins of each combination. But from each origin to existing 8 points
O1P1 = O1P2 = O2P1 = O2P2 = O3P3 = O3P4 = ...... = O8P8.
My lecturer just pointed out that we can one exact origin each combination points by using Isosceles Traiganle and Least Square Method.
Is there any way that we can solve this one?
Thank you so much

Comment: How do you form an angle from two points?

Comment: @Chrystomath This one default that we will get. In a real project, we can get it from the IMU sensor or another device to measure the angle.

Comment: If I understand, there is a sensor $S$ and the angle is eg $P_2SP_3$. Is $S$ at the origin $O$? And what do you mean by "also known as $OP1=OP2$" ?

Comment: Yes and origin O to P1 length is equal to the length of O to P2

Comment: Sorry, still can't understand. Is this in 3D? How do you get two origins from each pair $P1$, $P2$? What does the picture show exactly?

Comment: Ok, I think I start to understand. Did you solve the problem of getting the coordinates of $O1$, $O2$ from $P1$, $P2$? Can you share what you got?

Comment: Do you mean by procedure or example coordinate ?

Comment: @Chrystomath I have P1(1,2,2), P2(2,3,5) with angle 60 degrees and plane equation 1.15714286x + 1.8547619y-z-2.86101191=0 and after calculation, I got two origin O1(3.8623, 0.8854, 3.2507), O2(-0.867059, 4.1070, 3.7533).
I used plane equation, distance equation OP1 and OP2 and Cross Vector of product to calculation origin. After I used those 3 procedures, I got a quadratic equation and got those 2 origin.

Answer (score 1):

Use least squares to find that point which minimizes the errors in $|OP_i|=|OP_{i+1}|$. If $\mathbf{y}$ are the coordinates of the origin, and $\mathbf{p}_i$ are the coordinates of $P_i$, then $|\mathbf{p}_1-\mathbf{y}|=|\mathbf{p}_2-\mathbf{y}|$ gives $$2(\mathbf{p}_1-\mathbf{p}_2)\cdot\mathbf{y}=|\mathbf{p}_1|^2-|\mathbf{p}_2|^2$$ You can write these equations as a matrix equation $A\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{b}$. Then least squares gives $A^TA\mathbf{y}=A^T\mathbf{b}$. Solving this matrix equation gives the best $\mathbf{y}$.

For example, suppose we have the points $P=(-0.66,0.75,0.1)$, $(0.45,-0.88,0.2)$, $(0.26,0.97,0.3)$, $(-0.80,0.58,0.4)$, $(-0.97,0.15,0.5)$, $(-0.22,0.97,0.6)$. Then The first pair of points give the condition $|OP_1|=|OP_2|$, that is, $$2(-1.11, 1.63,-0.1)\cdot(y_1,y_2,y_3)=1.0081-1.0169=-0.0088$$ Repeating this for the other two pairs gives three equations: $$\begin{pmatrix}-2.22&3.26&-0.2\\2.12&0.78&-0.2\\-1.5& -1.64&-0.2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-0.0088\\-0.0379\\-0.1359\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $A^TAy=A^Tb$ is $$\begin{pmatrix}11.67&-3.12&0.32\\-3.12&13.93&-0.48\\0.32&-0.48& 0.12\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0.14\\0.16\\0.036\end{pmatrix}$$ which gives $(y_1,y_2,y_3)=(0.0089, 0.027, 0.39)$.

However, this procedure does not guarantee that $|OP|$ are all equal, just that they are equal in pairs. The condition $|OP_i|=|OP_j|$ for all $i,j$ is impossible to satisfy.

Comment: Could you write an example in matrix, I am still kind of not sure yet.
Thank you

Comment: Is there any means that 2(x1−x2)⋅y=|x1|2−|x2|2, I will get the new value of y and compare that y with those 2 origins?

Comment: What do you mean? Both 'origins' would satisfy that equation, so $y=O_1=O_2$. But you want a single vector $y$ which takes the place of half the origins, right?

Comment: If you mean "to solve $2(x_1-x_2)\cdot y=|x_1|^2-|x_2|^2$", then no that's not possible because it is one equation in two unknowns $y_1,y_2$.

Comment: Is that matrix applicable for 3D points because here we used it as 3D points?

Comment: Yes it's still applicable to 3D. The matrix $A$ then becomes $n\times3$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, but the same procedure applies.

Comment: for the 3D same procedure, are we still use 2(z1−z2)⋅y=|z1|2−|z2|2? and apply it to Ay=b, which A will be 3*3 matrics?

Comment: No!! $x_1=(x_{11},x_{12},x_{13})$, etc. It is a vector not an $x$-coordinate. I'll rewrite with new variables.

Comment: Thank you so much